# How to prove the following property of the matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If every element of a matrix $X$ is greater than zero and if $X=X^T$ then how can we show that $X$ is a positive definite matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't, because it's false. For instance, consider $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ b&d\end{pmatrix}$ with $a,d$ small and $b$ large.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then why in convex optimization book by Boyd after Eq. 2.3 its written that $P$ is positive definite matrix?

Comment: I don't know.${}$

Comment: @FrankMoses It says nowhere around Eq. 2.3 that $P$ has "all elements positive". Notation $P\succ 0$ means *positive definite*, just it.